# Restoring form state after unmount

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a form, mounted as a route within React Router, which serves as the central page. The form contains buttons navigating to other routes, each with a back button returning to the central form. Unfortunately, due to the nature of `redux-form` this means returning to the form clears the values.

What's the best redux-compliant way to build the form so it retains values until cleared manually?

Comment: Do you use redux ? You can store all form values in your redux state

Comment: I do yes - I was hoping to avoid storing duplicate values if possible. If I did go down this route, whereabouts is the best place to do this? and how do you cleanly re-hydrate the form state?

Comment: I would populate my state when navigating to other routes. It's duplicate only when you're on the current component and you are manipulating datas (by input on form for example), I don't think it's big deal. That's what redux is used for imho

Comment: For the re-hydrate part, just create state in your constructor and populate it with your redux data in your componentDidMount

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - but I'm using stateless components so I don't have state locally, plus I'd like to avoid leaving the redux pattern if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This course in egghead.io might helps [Redux: Persisting the State to the Local Storage](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-persisting-the-state-to-the-local-storage)